# iOS Simulator showing blurred

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I have just downloaded Xcode 9.0 and all the components. When I am trying to lunch simulator it is showing me blurred. I have restarted Xcode and Simulator but that doesn't help.This is happening with all the simulators. Am I missing any thing ?

[image]

Comment: try changing in "window" menu showing bezels

Comment: select the simulator in menu `Debug` check options there `Optimize rendering for window scale` this issue is related to `view rendering` and `scaling`.

Comment: By the way, what is the configuration of your Mac machine?

Comment: It works fine on Machine Restart